# Karate - multipart fields with json value getting response code as 400

Tags: multipartform-data, karate

I am trying to post multipart fields with JSON values. The same worked fine until the karate 0.9.6 version. Post upgrade to Karate 1.1.0, I am facing an error with response code 400.

When looking at the karate issues related to this, found this link https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1710 and hence upgraded the version to 1.2.0 and tried the solution as provided there, and still no luck.

Since I am a beginner in Karate, stuck here with a multipart request.

Below is a karate snippet,

```
Given path apiURL
* def jfile = read(input_json)
And multipart file jsondata = { value: '#(jfile)'}
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
When method post
Then status 200
```

and the value in **input_json** is,

```
{
    "cake": {
        "topping": "none",
        "batter": [
            {
                "id": "1001",
                "type": "Regular"
            },
            {
                "id": "1002",
                "type": "Chocolate"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Response**,

```
1 < 400
1 < Expires: 0
1 < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
1 < X-Powered-By: xxx
1 < Server: xxx
1 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
1 < Pragma: no-cache
1 < X-Frame-Options: DENY
1 < Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2022 14:41:11 GMT
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
1 < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=abc; Domain=localhost
```

I also tried multipart fields as below,
Karate snippet,

```
Given path apiURL
* def jfile = read(input_json)
And multipart fields jfile
And header Content-Type = 'multipart/form-data'
When method post
Then status 200
```

Still no luck. Getting same response code 400,

```
1 < 400
1 < Expires: 0
1 < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
1 < X-Powered-By: xxx
1 < Server: xxx
1 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
1 < Pragma: no-cache
1 < X-Frame-Options: DENY
1 < Date: Tue, 27 Sep 2022 15:07:34 GMT
1 < Connection: keep-alive
1 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
1 < Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=abc; Domain=localhost
```

Requesting assistance in resolving this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm really sorry that multipart is hard and it is impossible to troubleshoot remotely, you have to do it at your end. the only advice I can give is to read this: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1645#issuecomment-862502881